# SoapUI - Adding attachment in put request body

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud, soapui, cloud-foundry

I'm testing [this](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/238/apps/uploads_the_bits_for_an_app.html) REST API on BlueMix endpoint.

I'm going through it by trial and error, although I don't have any problem making other calls.

...Anyways, this request requires me to put binary zip file in message body. How can one do this in SoapUI?

So far my test request looks like this:

[image: Imagine that]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SoapUI - Working with REST Requests](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/working-with-rest-requests.html), specifically the *Attachments* section:

> **Attachments:** Contains any files that should be attached to the request as MIME attachments. If you want to associate the content of a file with any of the parameters when simulating a HTML multipart/form-data form then specify that parameters value as “file:”.

It also contains reference for other possible actions you can perform on the request.